# Difference in Python iter() function behavior in Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I defined a simple function to return the first item in an iterable, or an error:

```
def first(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    try:
        return next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("iterable is empty")
```

In the shell, this function does what you'd expect:

```
>>> first({"1st", "2nd", "3rd"})
'1st'
>>> first({"1st", "2nd", "3rd"})
'1st'
>>> first(["1st", "2nd", "3rd"])
'1st'
```

However, in Jupyter Notebook, it returns the second element in a `set`, but the first element in a `list`.

```
first({"1st", "2nd", "3rd"})
'2nd'

first(["1st", "2nd", "3rd"])
'1st'

first(set(["1st", "2nd", "3rd"]))
'2nd'
```

I'm using Python 3.6.5 in Anaconda in both cases.

Am I mising something obvious?

Comment: Sets have no defined order, is why.

Comment: Put differently: restart Jupyter, or run the same code again in any new Python interpreter. For string values, a random hash seed is used to prevent certain denial of service attacks.

Comment: Restarting Jupyter (kernel) didn't change the output. I'll check out your linked question, thanks; I didn't get to that LOD when searching to see if this question had been asked previously.

Comment: You only have 3 elements in the set, so there isn't much scope to see the difference that often.

Comment: Note that nothing in your question has anything to do with `iter()`. You could just paste `{"1st", "2nd", "3rd"}` into the terminal and see what order they are returned in. Run `python3 -c 'print({"1st", "2nd", "3rd"})'` a couple of times to see what happens. Jupyter is *not special here*.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the explanations.